# Select the names of wicketkeeper along with the number of sixes that they have hit (while batting)

Tags: sqlite

SELECT w.player, b.sixs FROM WicketKeeping w, Batting B ON W.player = b.player

The goal is to show All wicketkeepers along with all the number of sixs they have scored while batting.
Wicketkeeping and Batting are the tables. 
This is what i have currently, but it will not recognize b.player. How do i create two columns from two different. How do i combine two columns from tweo tables based on the wicketkeeping player being the same as batting player?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT w.player,
       b.sixs AS SixsWhileBatting
  FROM WicketKeeping w,
       batting b
 WHERE w.player IN (
           SELECT b.player
             FROM Batting b
             WHERE b.player = w.player
       ) and w.player = b.player;

Does this look right?